# distance_of_time_in_words with ActiveRecord TimeWithZone

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to use `distance_of_time_in_words` (Rails 3) on a `created_at` column of an ActiveRecord object.

But I get

```
ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone can't be coerced into Fixnum
```

when I call

```
distance_of_time_in_words(@user.created_at)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what does @user.created_at return?

Comment: also, distance_of_time_in_words takes in at least 2 variables. the from_time and to_time

Comment: well looking at the docos for the method, the "to" param is optional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to supply the `to_time` as well. Assuming you want to know "how long ago from right now":

```
<%= distance_of_time_in_words(@user.created_at, Time.now) %>
```

Alternatively, you could just do this:

```
<%= distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(@user.created_at) %>
```

Comment: distance_of_time_in_words_from_now does not exist according to my Rails! However the first option worked. Thanks

Comment: Oops, it's `to_now`, not `from_now`.